# R Shiny: tabSet isn't rendered with renderUI inside a navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I'm new to both R and Shiny. I'm trying to create a `tabPanel` in the `server.R` file with no success and I think it's because of a bug when using `uiContent` inside a `navbarPage` to get a `tabPanel`.

Here's my `ui.R`:

```
shinyUI(
    navbarPage(
        "test", id = "nav", collapsible = TRUE, position = "fixed-top",

        # needed to keep fixed-top navbar from obscuring content
        header = tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}"),

        uiOutput("content")
    )
)
```

And here's the `server.R`:

```
function(input, output) {
    output$content <- renderUI({
        tabPanel("tabA")
    })
}
```

My band-aid solution is to include the `navbarPage` function in `renderUI` but I'd like to know if there is some way to render tabs in the `server.ui` file while maintaining `navbarPage` in the `ui.R` file.

Answer (score 2):

After lengthy research, I don't believe it is possible.

When `navbarPage` is called on initial setup, it creates hyperlinks and placeholders for all `tabPanels`, that are given to it by input list. (See link below.) Any further additions that are injected by `uiOutput` won't do that, because the HTML context defining the `navbarPage` (not the content) is fixed after initiation. Any Injections will only influence displayed content in your tabs.

You could say, `shinyUI` knows no reactivity in the sense shinyServer does. BUT since reactivity in Shiny means nothing else than quick reevaluation, rebuilding your UI through `shinyServer` seems like a legit "Shiny" way to build dynamic `navbarPages`.

If youre still not satisfied you could search this page: [Shiny Bootstrap Definitions](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/bootstrap.R). Especially in Lines 306-389 (`navbarPage`) and 689-834 (`buildTabset`) you can read about actual function definitions. Maybe you could mimic those and add extra utilities in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the code below worked. Try to leave tabPanel in the ui, and render the rest (say you want a fluidpage) in the server like below.

```
shinyUI(
    navbarPage(
        "test", id = "nav", collapsible = TRUE, position = "fixed-top",

        # needed to keep fixed-top navbar from obscuring content
        header = tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}"),

        tabPanel("tabA",
        uiOutput("content"))
    )
)

function(input, output) {
    output$content <- renderUI({
        fluidPage("tabA content")
    })
}
```